# Jquery render issues on hide/show on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, render

This is some complex issue that i've spent countless hours trying to solve, no luck.

i am using phonegap, I decided not to use JQuery mobile because it has lots of css overrides and it injects some code into the DOM in addition to other stuff, so i am just using JQuery and i made some simple views system, there are articles and a main menu, on each article click i hide all other articles and menu, and on backbutton  i hide all and show menu only.
The annoying thing is that sometimes rarely when i try to show an article only (hide all others including menu) it would kind of render half of the article and half of the menu, but if i swipe it it will update as supposed to, *note that this issue doesn't appear on pc browsers, however it appears @least on android

```
 $("ul[class='article-listing'] li").each(function(i, e) {

           $(e).on("click",function(){
            goArticle((i+1))//called whenever the article list item is clicked
            })
            });

function goArticle(id)
 {  
 $$("div[id^='articleWrapper']").each(function(i, e) {
        if($$(e).attr("id") === "articleWrapper"+id)
        {   
        $(e).fadeIn(500);//show aricle of specified id
        }else{
        $(e).fadeOut(1);//hide article of specified id
        }
        })  
    if(location.hash !== '#articles')//set hash tag to articles if not set so that on back it always go to home
         $(location).attr('href', '#articles');
         $("#list").fadeOut(500);//hide menu

 }
```